# mysql statement in python but one variable has a space

Tags: mysql-python

I have a statement in python that is a SQL query but the problem is one of the variables has a space in it so it throws a syntax error. this is my statement where the second %s is a full name and idk how to make it work

```
sql_query = ('INSERT INTO tempSales(Account_Num,Customer_Name) VALUES (%s,%s);', row)
```

I've tried every which way I can think of to write this statement and it does not work

Comment: Concatenate?  IE --  `('INSERT INTO tempSales(Account_Num,Customer_Name) VALUES (\'' + %s + '\',\'' + %s + '\');', row)`

Comment: Can you provide an example which shows both the value of `row` and how `sql_query` is used?